# Error getting a collection of objects in Ruby from a belongs_to table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

In this example, I'm trying to get a collection of Workouts that have been created by specific types of users (a Workout belongs to a specific User, has column name user_id): either the current_user, a Professional user (inherits from User), and an admin. Here is what I have right now:

```
Workout.where('(user_id= ?) OR (user_id= ?) OR (user_id= ?)', current_user.id, User.select(&:professional?), User.find_by_admin(true).id)
```

I believe the second item is throwing this error:

> Mysql2::Error: Operand should contain 1 column(s): SELECT `workouts`.* FROM `workouts`  WHERE ((user_id= 29) OR (user_id= 2,5,29) OR (user_id= 2))
>   ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Operand should contain 1 column(s): SELECT `workouts`.* FROM `workouts`  WHERE ((user_id= 29) OR (user_id= 2,5,29) OR (user_id= 2))

If that's the case, how can I iterate over the user_id=2,5,29 (other than .each) and pull all the workouts that were created by this specific set of users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this `where` query, which will look into array of id's for `user_id` match

```
Workout.where(user_id: [current_user.id, User.select(&:professional?), User.find_by_admin(true).id].flatten)
```

Sql equivalent

`SELECT * FROM workouts WHERE user_id IN (1,3,6,4,2)`

Comment: Some of the entries in the array may be duplicated, like [29,2,5,29,2]. Is it OK to call `uniq` in order to get only the distinct values? Or it doesn't matter?

Comment: This query will find `user_id` in the array using `IN` operator. So I don't think it will matter. Still it's always good to use array without duplicate values

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Workout.where(user_id: [current_user, User.select(&:professional), User.find_by_admin(true)]).map(&:id)
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? Please add an explanation of what you did and why you did it that way not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.